# want to export Test Sets with complete associated test cases details(Name, Description, Steps, Priority, etc) from rally using ruby(RallyRestAPI)

Tags: ruby, testcase, rally

I am able to get Test Sets and associated test cases with only (name, description & priority) but not other details from rally using RallyRestAPI

I am using ruby

Please let me know how I can get other test case details(Steps, Priority, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving steps for test cases is similar to how you get the test cases associated to the test set. Steps and test case results are stored in an array on the test case object. I have written a small example showing how to get the steps and priority. Let me know if this helps.

```
query_result = rally.find_all(:test_set, 
                              :fetch => true, 
                              :project => 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/project/YOUR PROJECT OID HERE')

for i in (query_result)
  puts i.formatted_i_d + ": " + i.name
  #store test_cases in variable
  @test_case = i.test_cases
  for j in @test_case
    puts "   " + j.formatted_i_d.to_s+ ": " + j.to_s
    puts "      Priority: " + j.priority.to_s
    #store steps array in variable
    @steps = j.steps
    if @steps != nil
      for k in @steps
        puts "      Steps:"
        puts "         " + "Input: " + k.input
        puts "         " + "Expected Result: " + k.expected_result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulTheGeek, I am not getting steps(Input, Expected Result), I found a difference 'Validation' tag is getting added before Input and Expected Result. So, I am getting steps as Steps: Validation Input, Validation Expected Result. Please let me know all attributes for test cases and if any documnet/url then it will be more helpful

Comment: You can find all the webservices documentation at this url [WebServices API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/). Let me know if this is what you are looking for and if it helps.

Comment: Thank You @PaulTheGeek , I was following the same url but it does not give details of attribute names (like: FormattedID=>formatted_i_d, ValidationExpectedResult=>validation_expected_result, ValidationInput=>validation_input). I am able to get steps by using validation_expected_result & validation_input attribute.

Comment: The nomenclature for attribute names in the rally ruby rest api is not something that is documented unfortunately. It simply follows the ruby naming scheme where an underscore(_) is used instead of camel casing.